# Errors loading JSON with Flask and Angular

Tags: python, json, angularjs, flask

I've solved my issue, but I'd like to know what was going wrong so I can address it in the future. I'm having issues decoding incoming JSON for use in my Flask application.

**The code that sends it in Angular:**

```
$http.post("/login", JSON.stringify($scope.loginForm))
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("Submitting form failed!");
  });
```

Important to note that the request type is set to application/json earlier up, with

```
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
```

**The code that receives it within Flask:**

```
data = request.get_json()
email_address = data.get("email_address")
password = data.get("password")
```

Attempting to load it this way returns an error 400, but any other way leads to some very strange issues. For example:

```
return json.dumps(request.get_json())
```

Will log {"password": "password", "email_address": "email@email.com"} in the console, but attempting to do this:

```
data = request.get_json()
email_address = data.get("email_address")
password = data.get("password")
```

With no difference whatsoever between this and the first block of code except that I'm not forcing it, I receive the exception "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack". Which implies that there aren't two values to unpack.

HOWEVER, they both work individually. If I do the above request and omit either of the data.get() lines above, the other will work.

What about my setup causes my JSON object to disintegrate the first time it's accessed?

I got around this by using request.json instead of request.get_json() but as request.json is being deprecated it's fairly important I know how to solve this in the future. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can omit `JSON.stringify` and pass object directly to `$http.post()` method because angular will serialize it to JSON automatically it `formData` is object. So I assume that `JSON.stringify` will force angular to send is as `x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json` media type.

See default transformations section: [angular $http service documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)